# split an excel sheet based on a column value onto another empty workbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a question regarding splitting an excel master sheet into multiple sheets based on a column value. Currently I have solution splitting the sheet on that book itself. I need to split the master sheet onto another empty workbook without changing the Masterfile layout.

The current code also has an input dialog that I have to type which column. I will also be grateful if the column itself is embedded in the code itself without having to select which column.

```
Sub Splitdatabycol()

Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
Dim xTRg As Range
Dim xVRg As Range
Dim xWSTRg As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set xTRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the header rows:", "Kutools for Excel", "", Type:=8)

If TypeName(xTRg) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub

Set xVRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the column you want to split data based on:", "Kutools for Excel", "", Type:=8)

If TypeName(xVRg) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub

vcol = xVRg.Column
Set ws = xTRg.Worksheet
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = xTRg.AddressLocal
titlerow = xTRg.Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('xTRgWs_Sheet!A1')") Then
    Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "xTRgWs_Sheet"
Else
    Sheets("xTRgWs_Sheet").Delete
    Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "xTRgWs_Sheet"
End If

Set xWSTRg = Sheets("xTRgWs_Sheet")
xTRg.Copy
xWSTRg.Paste Destination:=xWSTRg.Range("A1")
ws.Activate

For i = (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count) To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
Next

myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear

For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If

    xWSTRg.Range(title).Copy
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Paste Destination:=Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    ws.Range("A" & (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count) & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A" & (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count))
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next

xWSTRg.Delete
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).